# Connecting ODBC to AzureDatabricks using Simba Driver

Tags: azure, odbc, databricks, azure-databricks

I am simply trying to setup an ODBC driver to Databricks Cluster.
**According to the MS documentation**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/bi/jdbc-odbc-troubleshooting
If you get an TTransport exception using the curl command, you successfully reached and authenticated.

**When I run...**

```
curl https://adb-77180857967XXXXX.6.azuredatabricks.net:443/sql/protocolv1/o/7718085796704186/0910-172424-pizza885 -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXX"
```

**It does produce the error which indicates success...**

```
Error 500 Server Error
HTTP ERROR 500
<p>Problem accessing /cliservice. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

**When I test the connection from the ODBC driver I get the following error:**
FAILED!
[Simba][ThriftExtension] (14) Unexpected response from server during a HTTP connection: Could not resolve host for client socket..

Answer (score 1):

please try to check sigma connect where you setup HTTPS options and SSL options correct If not please follow below steps.

HTTPS Option:
You get HTTP Path from databricks connection details.

SSL Options: checked below box checked
-  Enable SSL
- Use System Trust Store